# Mock class with static method to execute test case in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, powermockito

Hi I have a class with static method as below

```
@Log4j2
@Profile("!ut")
@Component('CALC')
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = 'CALC', havingValue = 'VAL')
public class
ClassA extends ClassMain {
    public static org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger narrLogger;

    @Autowired
    IHCRefDataMgr ihcRefDataMgr;
    
    public ClassA(IHCRefDataMgr ihcRefDataMgr) {
        super(ihcRefDataMgr);
        this.ihcRefDataMgr = ihcRefDataMgr;
    }

    public boolean calculate(msg) {
        narrLogger = Narratives.getNarrativeLogger(msg)
    }
}
```

I have another class where i trace the logs

```
@Data
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = 'CALC', havingValue = 'VAL')
@Log4j2
public class ClassB {

    Boolean prepareMap() {
        Boolean status = true;
        try {
            Set<String> securityKeys = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
            ClassA.narrLogger.trace("Security Keys for given BA:  {}", securityKeys);
            // doing some processing
        } catch (Exception e) {
            status = false;
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to write a test case for ClassB, In my debugger when I come to ClassA.narrLogger, i get null pointer exception. How can i mock ClassA and allow it to pass assuming i dont want to test narrLogger.

Test Case

```
@Log4j2
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.profiles.active=test,ut", "calculator.name = ClassA", "eureka.client.enabled = false"})
public class ClassBTest {
    
    ClassB classb;

    @Test
    public void prepareMapTest() {
        var status = classb.prepareMap();
        Assertions.assertEquals(true, status)
    }
}
```

While running test case, it falls in exception as null pointer comes at ClassA.narrLogger

Comment: Where's the static method?

Comment: Can't you simply assign an empty (or command line) logger to `narrLogger` field before executing your test?

Comment: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger narrLogger;

Comment: That's a static field, not a method. It's public, why don't you just assign it in the setup of your tests?

Comment: Is it possible for you to write a sample test for the class. setup basically, i might be missing something. I am mocking classA but this gives null pointer

Comment: You cannot mock a field, you can only mock methods. Assign the field in your test `ClassA.narrLogger = ...`

Comment: without a minimal, _reproducible_ example, I can't see a way to properly answer your question

Comment: Updated question, if it gives you an idea what i am trying to test.

Comment: I'm still not sure why you don't want to set the field? Even in production code, it will be null. More questions though: 1) why are you having 2 loggers in your class? 2) why is class B calling the logger of class A?